# Testar um App no android. React Native

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, debug, virtualbox

Olá, meu notebook não tem a opção de ativar a virtualização, então eu preciso de um jeito de testar um app que estou fazendo. 
Alguém conhece uma maneira de eu fazer isso no meu próprio smartphone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expo é a solução pra você.
Dê uma olhada aqui: https://expo.io/tools

Mas basicamente, você instala o APP **Expo** no seu celular, instala também no projeto:

```
npm install expo-cli --global
```

Ele vai gerar um QR code e você usa o APP no celular pra escanear esse QR

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer isso tanto usando o Expo ou a outra CLI. Mas se o projeto for simples e não precisar de muitas configurações nativas eu recomendo o expo. Basta executar o comando: `expo start`

Que ele irá gerar um qrcode, e ao lê-lo usando o aplicativo do Expo, você pode testar o projeto no seu celular.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode utilizar o Expo como já citaram aí ou debugar diretamente no seu celular via usb. Basta habilitar seu celular para debugar nas opções de desenvolvedor.